# Can this Button be considered as Material design?

Tags: android, google-material-design

I've read the material.io page and tried it myself ,in a button on an android test - app. but there are 2 things which I think are nice but don't know if they fit into the material design guidlines:

- The black borders
- the 'not round but angular' corners

[here is a screen- recording of the app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DER5OA2S9og)

Comment: Can you just add a copy of the button as an image?  WHy do we have to watch a video to answer this?

Comment: Most buttons are clickable. So my button comes with an animation. To show this, I decided to record my screen instead of rendering a gif.

Comment: The question isn't about the animation...

Comment: No. As the title reveals, the question is about the button , which contains 2 states: clicked and not clicked. The 2 states are connected together through the animation. So the animation is part of the button.

Comment: What do you mean by material design? I am not familiar.

Comment: It's the 'design codex' by google for android application and so on. visit material.io it explains everything

Answer (score 1):

The guideline mentions outlined buttons (https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#outlined-button), but no buttons with a color AND an outline.
If you want to keep the button yellow, you should remove the outline but add a shadow.

The guideline allows cut corners, see the Shrine Material Theme on https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#theming

Apart from that:

- the green effect does not respect the cut corners
- the button should have an offset from the top and left
- the button appears too big, the guidline mentions a height of 36dp
- maybe this is my personal taste, but I think the colors look bad. I can't exactly point my finger at it. Maybe there are just too many different colors, maybe it is the yellow.

Answer (score 0):

"Material Design", suggested by Google in 2014, is the name of a new visual language for Web page User Interface used on Google's platforms such as Chrome OS and the Web.
The overall look is summarized on [http:thenextweb.com](https://thenextweb.com/google/2014/06/26/google-explains-principles-material-design-language-android-chrome-web/#.tnw_tED3cIyC)

The features of Material Design are to provide a bold, vibrant, and consistent look for visual products. It is intentional design where any motion used must provide meaning.

As you illustrate your button and its action, I do not believe it fits the Material Design guidelines.
Your button art is flat rather than appearing as a tangible surface apart from the background. A slight drop-shadow emphasizes the "feel" of real materials rather than artwork. A Material Design button appears to "BE" a button by virtue of the dimensional appearance as real material would.